# Sum(?) with mysqli returns 0 or wrong result when prepared and bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I want to sum up a row in Mysql using php with mysqli and prepared statements. When I am using a prepared statement and bind the param it returns the wrong result (some 200...):

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT SUM($user) FROM $datenbankid WHERE namepayer=?");
$value = "clemens";

if(!$stmt->bind_param("s", $value)){
    $response["errormessage"] = $stmt->error;       
    }
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($sum);
    $stmt->fetch();

    $response["debtsan" . $value] = $sum;

    $stmt->close();
```

But when I use it without bind_param it returns the right amount:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT SUM($user) FROM $datenbankid WHERE namepayer = Clemens");

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($sum);
    $stmt->fetch();

    $response["debtsantest" . $value] = $sum;

    $stmt->close();
```

I get no errors and without the bind param it is working. But I want to use the bind_param to avoid sql injection.

Thanks for helping. 
Demian

Comment: are you sure that `$value` is not empty or/and it's string

Comment: I can return the $value and it is the string "clemens" like I defined it.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Comment: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'error_reporting' edit: just a typo. no additional errors.

Comment: The second query should return an error of the form that `Clemens` is an undefined column.  Are you sure these samples are really the code you are running?

Comment: directly copied from the script. the second quer returns: debtsantestclemens : 1223.....

Answer (score 0):

can you try with this code, leave your query as it as use this code below the query

```
$value = "clemens";
    if($stmt === false) {
        $response["errormessage"] =$mysqli->error;       
    }
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $value);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($sum);
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
       printf("%i\n", $sum);
    }
```

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Comment: in this case you can use `$stmt->bind_result($sum);` as you are using and print the value

Comment: last thing you can also try by adding it in your sql like `SELECT SUM($user) as sum`

Comment: how do I get the sum then? If I use mysqli_fetch_array it says it isn't a mysqli_result but an object.